# sef url does not works in my custom menu module for joomla 2.5

Tags: php, httprequest, joomla2.5

I developed a module to display submenus as stand alone module, every thing works fine untill the sef is enabled, the item id does not change to the correct one

```
<ul class="list2">

                    <?php foreach ($items as $row) :?>
                    <?php

                        //$router = JSite::getRouter();
                        if ($router->getMode() == JROUTER_MODE_SEF) {

                            $link = $router->build($row->link);
                            $router->setVar('Itemid',$row->id);
                            echo $_REQUEST['Itemid'];
                            //$link =$row->alias;
                        }else {
                            $link = $row->link.'&Itemid='.$row->id;
                        }

                    ?>
```

I tried using the JSITE::route even router->build and tried to reset $_Request['Itemid']
and nothing worked

what I do wrong, any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution, just need to change the item id before creating the link

```
$router->setVar('Itemid',$row->id);
$link = $router->build($row->link);
```

hopfully this will help other developers :)